# Flutter: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled, if add google_app_id manual in style.xml, then app is showing blank

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I am trying to add Firebase Analytics in flutter project. after adding all reqirement things like: flutterfire_cli activate, and also added firebase_options.dart file. I am getting 'Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled' issue.

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics/observer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future  main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

  navigatorObservers: [
    FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: FirebaseAnalytics.instance),
  ],

  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(

    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
    useMaterial3: true,
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(),
);
}
}
```

if I add Google_app_id in style.xml, then analytics is working perfect but app is showing blank. so please help me out.

[google_app_id missing error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOVCC.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: I have code part also

Answer (score 0):

Since Flutter 3.16.4 the Gradle setup has changed by default on all new apps, resulting in breaking the flutter-fire CLI automatic configuration.

You must configure the Android gradle yourself.

Here's what worked for me.

./android/settings.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.8.1" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.firebase-perf" version "1.4.2" apply false
}
```

Note: the versions might be outdated, it is either that this post is too old or that one is not compatible with others. ex: firebase-perf (1.4.2) is only compatible with google-services:4.3.15 and kotlin (1.9.0)

./android/app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}
```

```
android {
    ...
    compileSdk 34
    ...
    defaultConfig {
      ...
      minSdkVersion 28
      targetSdkVersion 34
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.9.0"
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-perf")
}
```

./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<application>
    ....
    <meta-data
      android:name="firebase_performance_logcat_enabled"
      android:value="true" />
    ....
</application>
```